# How to change the date format of column in DataTable?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2013.I have one data table "dt" which contains many columns having  date time format.I want to change the values in all that columns into "yyyy/mm/dd" format.Remember all the datetime columns can contain null value also.
I have used this code,but not getting any changes in "dt".

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        var inv = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()

                  .Select(col => col.DataType == typeof(DateTime)
                    ? row.IsNull(col) ? " " : row.Field<DateTime>(col).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", inv)
                    : row.IsNull(col) ? "" : row[col].ToString());


            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }
```

Comment: How are you displaying said table?  This a console app? Windows Forms? WPF?  Other?

Comment: i am working on ASP.NET web application ,the data table is retrieved from sql database and now now whatever i am having in data table, i want it to export to excel but date format should be like as mentioned above.